# Learn C The Hard Way exercise 14 Error (warning: array subscript has type ?char? [-Wchar-subscripts]

Tags: c

I'm following along that tutorial, I'm running WindowsXP 32-bit with cygwin compiler, The tutorial asks me to run this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// forward declarations
int can_print_it(char ch);
void print_letters(char arg[]);

void print_arguments(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        print_letters(argv[i]);
    }
}

void print_letters(char arg[])
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; arg[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char ch = arg[i];

        if(can_print_it(ch)) {
            printf("'%c' == %d ", ch, ch);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int can_print_it(char ch)
{
    return isalpha(ch) || isblank(ch);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    print_arguments(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

But I keep running into this warning:

```
$ make ex14
cc -Wall -g    ex14.c   -o ex14
ex14.c: In function ?can_print_it?:
ex14.c:34:5: warning: array subscript has type ?char? [-Wchar-subscripts]
    return isalpha(ch) || isblank(ch);
    ^
ex14.c:34:5: warning: array subscript has type ?char? [-Wchar-subscripts]
```

I have tried searching around, while I have found a lot of threads talking about a similar error, none of their answers/solutions worked on my code, and I couldn't find a question related to *Learn C The Hard Way* [exercise 14](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex14.html).

So what should I do to get rid of that warning?

Comment: Does the code work anyway? It's throwing a warning, not an error... (By the way, I'm amazed that there is a "learn-c-the-hard-way" tag :)

Comment: `(unsigned char)ch` . The standard mandates the passed value to both of those ([`isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) and [`isblank`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isblank)) must be representable as `unsigned char` or the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @AjPerez, whoa my bad, It actually works, I still want to get rid of that warning though

Comment: I do not understand why the compiler considers char index as dangerous, but you can change `can_print_it(char ch);` to `can_print_it(int ch);` to fix it.

Comment: @Marian That raised two more errors

Comment: @WhozCraig I have tried that, two more errors

Comment: @Marian: No, this doesn't fix it. And this is a potentially subtle bug, as basic characters are positive, so it is observable only for `char` values bigger than `CHAR_MAX` (and only if `char` is signed).

Comment: You shall probably change it also in the declaration, i.e. `int can_print_it(char ch);` to `int can_print_it(int ch);`

Comment: That what I've Tried @Marian

Comment: Can't see it on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78427441d9eb1b84), but I'm pretty sure its in your implementation. both of those appear to be *macros* indexing into lookup tables; not functions. trace down their decls and you'll probably find that is the case.

Comment: What i don't understand is that the tutorial uses 2 functions from `ctype.h` instead of just using `isprint()`.? why would that be?

Comment: @iharob because they want to use heavier restriction than just printable. The goal of the poorly named `can_print_it` is to exclude all but alphabetic chars or spaces. Punctuation, digits, etc, are all excluded, where they would not be with `isprint`.

Comment: @WhozCraig you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the warning is that char values are usually positive, but sometimes they may be negative; this may come unexpected to the programmer (especially because on some implementations char is always positive), and using a negative index for an array is obviously a bad thing.

isalpha does exactly that behind your back. You fix the warning by casting the char to int or by storing it in an int in the first place - this doesn't fix the problem though, because a negative char will be cast to a negative int which has exactly the same problem. You can fix the warning and the problem by casting the char to an unsigned char.

Comment: Changing both of the functions to accept unsigned char's has worked

Comment: The compiler shouldn't warn for this. The _default argument promotions_ ensure that the char is converted to an int through integer promotion. The original signedness of char for the given implementation is therefore completely irrelevant, as it will always be converted to a (signed) int. Furthermore, there are no arrays in the function can_print_it(). Therefore I believe the correct answer is "the compiler warning is broken".

Answer (score 3):

So if we look at the [gcc document for warnings which covers -Wchar-subscripts](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) it says:

> Warn if an array subscript has type char. This is a common cause of error, as programmers often forget that this type is signed on some machines. This warning is enabled by -Wall.

It is implementation defined whether *char* is signed or unsigned, if you use an *unsigned char* then the warning will go away.

We can see from the draft C99 standard that the arguments to functions in `<ctype.h>` are expected to be representable as *unsigned char* or `EOF`, from section `7.4` *Character handling <ctype.h>*:

> In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be
>   representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro EOF. If the
>   argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined

So most likely `isalpha` and `isblank` are implemented as a macro which uses a lookup table and so this code would indeed be using a char to index an array.

Comment: If isalpha etc are implemented as macros, the implementation (compiler) is broken, because making them macros would remove the default argument promotion of char to an int, which the programmer will expect to happen, since they are functions. And there are no arrays in the function can_print_it(), so the compiler should not give this warning.

Answer (score 0):

The input type of `isalpha` and `isblank` is expected to be `int`, not `char`. That's the core issue. The rest are details of how those are implemented. If use the `-E` flag to just pre-process the code, the function `can_print_it` expands to:

```
int can_print_it(char ch)
{
    return (((__ctype_ptr__+sizeof(""[ch]))[(int)(ch)])&(01|02)) || __extension__ ({ __typeof__ (ch) __x = (ch); (((__ctype_ptr__+sizeof(""[__x]))[(int)(__x)])&0200) || (int) (__x) == '\t';});
}
```

As you can see, the input, `ch`, is used as an array index in the implementation of `isalpha`. A temporary, `__x`, which is of the same type as `ch`, is use as an array index in the implementation of `isblank`.

You can fix the warnings by:

1. Changing the argument type of `can_print_it` to `int`.

   ```
   int can_print_it(int ch)
   {
       return isalpha(ch) || isblank(ch);
   }
   ```
2. Creating a temporary variable in the function and using it to call `isalpha` and `isblank`.

   ```
   int can_print_it(char ch)
   {
       int temp = ch;
       return isalpha(temp) || isblank(temp);
   }
   ```

Comment: Both would fix the warnings, but *neither* will fix the negative-index lookup when passed a high-ascii value, which is exactly what that warning is designed to address. The  former (1) is closer to the metal, but to properly invoke it requires `if(can_print_it((unsigned char)ch))` to ensure the conversion to `int` doesn't fall right back in to a negative index. (and btw, I did *not* downtick this).

Comment: @WhozCraig, If an `int` is accepted as a valid argument to `isalpha` and `isblank`, which can be a negative value in theory, it's not clear to me how `gcc` is protecting the use with this warning.

Comment: Because when `int` is passed it is *not* promoted (its already `int`). If said-`int` was negative (and it certainly can be, as the type is *definitely* signed), well, it sucks to be the guy passing a negative `int`. But `char` *may* be signed (usually is). It is (a) promoted to `int`, and (b) if signed *and* negative, will have said-sign extended during the promotion. So joe sixpack not knowing his `char` may actually be a signed-negative value will find out the hard way.

Comment: And btw, your *second* alternative would work if `int temp = (unsigned char)ch;` were the temporary, though I still think the first is more-correct, putting the onus on the caller to do the cast, just like all the standard ctype `iswhatever` functions.

Comment: @RSahu: On some systems the "é" character (for example) is represented by a `char` that is negative. The rules for `isalpha` etc specify that the value passed to them must be representable by an `unsigned char` (or EOF, but let's ignore that case for now), which negative numbers are not.

Comment: @RSahu: The warning isn't intended to indicate wrong `isalpha` etc usage, but using `char` as array indexes. That OP's implementation chooses to use a macro function with array indexing for `isalpha` just makes the warning also appear for those functions (the warning is nonetheless correct, it just isn't as useful, because it doesn't cover other (very similar) wrong usages of `isalpha`).

Comment: @mafso, the parts of `gcc` that deals with `-Wchar-subscripts` is coming into conflict with the parts of `gcc` that implements `isalpha` (and other `is<something>` functions). An `int` is valid argument to `isalpha`. Using a `char` where an `int` is expected should not be cause for compiler warnings. It's gcc's bad, IMHO.

Comment: @RSahu, no it's UB to pass something else than a value representable as an `unsigned char` (or `EOF`), see Shafik's answer. `isalpha` is not obliged to do the `unsigned char` conversion on its own (this design, in turn, is indeed questionable, but that's not GCC's bad).

Comment: @mafso, I understand that. I find it strange that gcc, or any compiler for that matter, would produce warning when a `char` is used where an `int` is expected -- be it in a function call or in a macro.

Comment: I agree that the warning is strange in this case. It's nonetheless justified in most cases (as in this one), so nothing to fix here for Gcc, IMO. (Btw, <ctype.h> is not part of GCC, but of the C library, I think, and I don't know which one is used with cygwin.) Anyway, the solution shown here shuts down the compiler while keeping the bug, which isn't really an improvement.

Comment: The warning comes because GCC does not perform the mandatory default argument promotion of the parameter: by making the function a macro, they have goofed this up. It appears that this warning is gone in later versions of GCC. There is no need for any explicit casts anywhere, as there is nothing wrong with the code. The warning is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your compiler is old or broken. GCC 4.9.1 compiles this code with no warnings/errors, given:

```
gcc test.c -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra
```

The compiler is obliged to implicitly promote your char to the int that the isalpha etc functions require. It will do this promotion no matter the implementation-defined signedness of char. The size of char should not matter either, since char is always a small integer type.

The only kind of warning I'd expect a compiler to give from this code is something along the lines of "implicit conversion from char to int".